# Retain the clicked value of a button and autorefesh with Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am an entry level php guy. I am trying to create a one-on-one chat program with php for the backend and Jquery for the client end. My code works like this, upon click of button, the value of the selected user is stored in a Jquery variable and passed on to the PHP side, which brings out the conversation between two users.
Now, the challenge is how do I auto refresh this conversation (the result) every 10 secs or so.

Here's my code.

```html
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked mail-nav">

<?php
    $output .= '
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked mail-nav">
    <li><a href="#" class="getuser">
    <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i>'.$user.'</a></li>
    </ul>';
?>

<div class="sender">
    <form id="theform" > 
        <input type="text" name="messages"  placeholder="Send Message">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="geek"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here's the jquery script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".getuser").click(function () { 
        var value = $(this).text(); 
        load_comment();

        function load_comment() {
            $.ajax({
                url:"getMessage.php",
                method: "GET",
                data: {
                    'getvalue':
                },
                success:function (data) {
                    $('.messages').html(data);
                    ///upon success scroll to bottom of message
                    $("#bottom").get(0).scrollIntoView({
                        behavior: "smooth", block: "end", inline: "nearest"}); 
                    }
                });
            setTimeout(function(){
            location.reload();
            },5000);
        }
    });
</script>
```

**and the getMessage.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('config.php');
$Logged=$_SESSION['t_user'];

if(isset($_GET['getvalue'])) { 
$b = $_GET['getvalue'];
//store $b in a session
$_SESSION['getvalue'] = $b;
$thread = $_SESSION['getvalue'];

$sqlf= $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM usermessages WHERE (userto = '$b' OR 
userto = '$Logged') 
AND (userfrom = '$Logged' OR userfrom = '$b') ORDER BY timecreated ASC ");

$sqlf->execute();
$row=$sqlf->FetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$output = '';

if ($sqlf)
{///updating the value of seen
$up=$conn->prepare("UPDATE usermessages SET viewed= 1 WHERE (userto = '$b' 
OR userto = '$Logged') 
AND (userfrom = '$Logged' OR userfrom = '$b')");
$up->execute();
}
?>
<?PHP
foreach ($row as $r) 
{
$sender = $r['userfrom'];
$m = $r['messages'];

///time to get the user's thumb
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM employees where t_user = ? limit 1 ");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $sender);
$stmt->execute();
$th=$stmt->FetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($th as $p) 
{
$thumb = $p['passport'];
}

$output .= '

<div class="message">
<img src="'.$thumb.'" width="50" height ="50">
<p class="info">'.$m.'</p>
</div>';
}
}
echo  "You are chatting with $b";
echo $output;

echo '<div id="bottom"></div>';
?>
```

Comment: You missed to send value of the text in ajax data.

Comment: dont reload entire page, just call ajax and append new data to ul for every 10 sec.

Comment: @Devsi Odedra, can you explain more, please

Answer (score 0):

Simply call `load_comment()` function on every 10 seconds, assuming that `load_comment()` is the function for conversation .

```
setTimeout(function(){
load_comment();
},10000);
```

Comment: This works partially, in the sense that auto refresh occurs every io secs and brings out the conversations btwn the two users but if I click on another user, different from the other two users, its sort of glitches between the two clicks.